# Parsing a list and create expressions

Tags: python, sympy

I have a list of strings:

```
A = ['a','b']
```

I want to parse this list and write following expressions:

```
a = x**2
b = a*x
```

where `x` is a `sympy` symbol and later on I will use these expressions for other operations like differentiation and so on. The problem is that `a` and `b` are strings inside the list. I am not being able to use them as expressions! How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you don't.  Trying to set up dynamic variable names is usually a sign of poor design.  If you *do* need those symbols to represent things to the outside world, try keeping a label and a value.  For instance, a dictionary can do something like this for you.

```
symbol = { 'a': x**2; 'b': x**3 }
```

You can add symbols from there, change values, etc.  For instance,

```
symbol = { 'a': x**2 }
symbol['b'] = symbol['a'] * x
```

---

Granted, you can build an expression string and use `eval` on the contents, but this is generally dangerous and hard to maintain well.

A wider possibility is to manipulate string values and write the Python script you'd like to run.  Write it to a file and then use the `os` or `subprocess` commands to execute it.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: I tried using a dictionary. But how will you use it eventually in sympy differentiation as `a` and `b` (keys of dictionary symbol) are still strings?

Comment: Can you get the job done by using a list/array of values?  You *can* dig into your main program's stack object and add variables, but that's even touchier than `eval`.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. I guess I can make it work using a dictionary.